# get multiple return from function and use them in different arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function generateRandomAnimals(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimal());
    }
    return arr;
}

function generateRandomAnimalsNames(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimal());
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomAnimal(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length);
    var animal = animals[rand];
    var animalName = animalNames[rand];
    return animal;
    return animalName;
}
```

i want to push the animal returned to the generateRandomAnimals Array and animalName returned to the generateRandomAnimalsNames Array. but since we can't return two values from one function, how can we return them and use them separately to push in different arrays given above?
note: animals and animalNames are different arrays created with number of elements to choose from.

Comment: Try returning an array that contains all items

Comment: Do you expect the entries returned by `generateRandomAnimals` to correspond to the entries in `generateRandomAnimalsNames` ? The whole setup seems a bit strange to me so I'm not sure what to suggest here. What is it that you ultimately want to achieve? I.e. what data you want to get in the end?

Comment: @ felix king. yes thats what i want.    it is a matching app to match name of the animal with its pic. that's why i need same random number to be applied on both arrays(animal and animal Name). but the solution you gave is generating different random numbers for both. is there any way to generate same random numbers to get same index number from both arrays?

Answer (score 1):

This answer might or might not help, depending on the rest of your code and your ultimately goal. It assumes that the return values of `generateRandomAnimals` and `generateRandomAnimalsNames` are independent.

From what you posted, a slightly better code design would be to have a generic "pick random element from array" function and have `generateRandomAnimals` and `generateRandomAnimalsNames` pass the desired array. Then there is no need to "return multiple values".

```
function generateRandomAnimals(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomElement(animalNames));
    }
    return arr;
}

function generateRandomAnimalsNames(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomElement(animals));
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomElement(array){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
    return array[rand];
}
```

Another solution would be to store animals and their names in a single array.

Comment: You thought of the problem 1 layer deeper than I did, congrats!

Comment: it is a matching app to match name of the animal with its pic. that's why i need same random number to be applied on both arrays(animal and animal Name). but the solution you gave is generating different random numbers for both. is there any way to generate same random numbers to get same index number from both arrays?

Answer (score 1):

**You can only use one `return` statement, true. But, if you want to return more than one value, you can just use an object (very similar to an associative array in a language like PHP):**

```
var animal = animals[rand];
var animalName = animalNames[rand];
return {
    "animal": animal,
    "animalName": animalName
};
```

And then you can grab each individual item from the object using this syntax: `obj["property_name"]`.

However, since you are not making any use of both values in each of the functions (`generateRandomAnimals` and `generateRandomAnimalsNames`), I believe it would be better and more beautiful if your code looked like this (considering that your `animals` and `animalNames` variables look like what I think they look like):

```
var animals = [{"name": "Dog"}, {"name": "Cat"}, {"name": "Cow"}];
var animalNames = ["Dog", "Cat", "Cow"];

function generateRandomAnimals(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimal());
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomAnimal() {
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length);
var animal = animals[rand]; 
return animal;
}

function generateRandomAnimalsNames(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimalName());
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomAnimalName(){
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length);
var animalName = animalNames[rand];
return animalName;
}

var random_animals = generateRandomAnimals(5);
var random_animal_names = generateRandomAnimalsNames(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can return an object, like an array or plain object:

```
function generateRandomAnimals(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimal().animal); // get property of interest
    }
    return arr;
}

function generateRandomAnimalsNames(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimal().animalName); // get property of interest
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomAnimal(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length);
    var animal = animals[rand];
    var animalName = animalNames[rand];
    return { animal, animalName }; // return object with 2 properties (ES6 short notation)
}
```

Although this may answer your question, it looks to me you are dividing things that belong together into two separate arrays, where only the index in one array determines where to find the other value that goes with it.

It is much better practice to use objects, in this case with two properties, like is returned by the modified `randomAnimal` function. You could just push those objects *as a whole* on *one* array:

```
function generateRandomAnimals(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomAnimal()); // now you have both properties
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomAnimal(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length);
    var animal = animals[rand];
    var animalName = animalNames[rand];
    return { animal, animalName }; // return object with 2 properties (ES6 short notation)
}
```

You can then access one such animal like this:

```
var arr = generateRandomAnimals(10);
console.log(arr[0].animal, arr[0].animalName);
```

Comment: animal and animal array are equal except that aniaml[i] has url and animalName[i] has its name respectively.                                                                the above syntax provides different arrays for both of them like from animal arrays it chooses i = 5, 9, 11 and from animalName arrays it chooses i = 4, 8, 15.                                                                                        since their random number are same and the elements correspond with each other, aren't they suppose to choose the same index numebrs from the array?

Comment: Yes, and what do you want to tell me with that?